# proof related to cut vertex in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

I need a help to prove graph theory question.
statement is **"Graph G is connected and there is no cut vertex in G. and If we are picking up any two vertices from the graph G then they should lie on a cycle."**

How can we prove this?

Comment: I think you want [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)...

Answer (score 0):

Only statements (formulas) can be proved. This does not sound like a statement. How is G quantified? Such properties are not true for every graph G.

Also, what is "cut vertex"? Do you mean a vertex cut consisting of a single vertex?

Comment: you have a connected graph and it has no cut vertex (check out the def of cut vertex). as I've clearly mentioned. graph is connected so obviously not a single vertex.

Comment: @CheTanNeve I think you mean "Then, if we are picking ..." instead of "and if we are picking". There should be an implication.